# Converting C++ code from VS 2005 to VS 2008? What does that even mean?

Tags: c++

Ok, I kinda got an assignment, and I am not sure what it means.

The guy told me that I would be "converting" code from older version of VS to a newer one, not sure about the versions he really said, but lets take that these I said are correct.
Language is C++, and what am I supposed to do here? I mean, what are the differences in VS's?

Maybe I misunderstood what he said, but anyway I'm lost, help anyone?

Comment: TBH You're moving from an entirely outdated version of Visual Studio to an entirely outdated version, if you're really going to 2008. A saner target would be 2013 or 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following would be the typical sequence of tasks:

- Load the old VS2005 project file in VS2008
- VS2008 will prompt to convert the project file to VS2008 format, do that
- Build the project
- Fix anything that is flagged as an error by the newer compiler
- Test the resulting compiled code

Of course the C++ language itself did not change between those years. Other things about VS might have.

Comment: The C++ language didn't change, both theoretically implement C++03, but in practice there were quite some updates. Microsoft was mostly working on C#, not C++, around 2000-2005.

Comment: Alright, so I did understood him. Thank you very much,